# Сглаживание графика с текстовой x осью

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Мне нужно сгенерировать график, который бы показывал собранную статистику по часам. Я делал это с помощью matplotlib и получалось примерно следующее:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_plot(x,y1, name_y1,name_x,name_y,name_plot):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y1, label=name_y1, color='#8B008B', linewidth=2) 
    plt.fill_between(x, y1, 0, facecolor='#6A5ACD', interpolate=True, alpha=0.7)

    plt.scatter(x[-1], y1[-1], color='#8718a3', s=30, marker='o') 
    plt.scatter(x[0], y1[0], color='#8718a3', s=30, marker='o')

    ax.set_xlabel(name_x) 
    ax.set_ylabel(name_y) 
    ax.set_title(name_plot)
    plt.xticks(rotation=60, horizontalalignment='center',)
    ax.legend() 
    fig.tight_layout()
    ax.grid(alpha=0.5) 
    plt.show()

generate_plot(["01:00", "02:00", "03:00", '04:00', '05:00', '06:00'], 
              [1,3,4,3,6,2], 
              "Линия", 
              "Значения x", 
              "Значения y", 
              "График")
```

[image: График который сейчас имеется]

Я захотел сгладить углы, чтобы это смотрелось красивее.
Я пробовал:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([1,6,3,7,4,9])
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
xnew = np.linspace(1, 6, num=41, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro',xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.legend(['data', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: Сглаженный график]

Но такой вариант работает только если массив данных x - это числа.
Вопрос: Как мне сгладить график где x - это строчки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сглаживайте по цифрам на оси `x`, как вы это делаете, а потом просто переподпишите отметки на оси нужным текстом вместо цифр:

```
...
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4,5,6], ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00", '04:00', '05:00', '06:00'])
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]